# I want to post form data through button in while loop. Is it possible in this way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, axios

This is the code I tried to post form data while looping

```
<?php
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row12 = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
?>
<form class="yatis"id="foo" method="POST">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <span class="text-sm font-semibold text-black dark:text-black">
            <?php echo $row12["sched2"]; ?>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" id="unq" name="unq" value="<?php echo $row["unique_id"]; ?>">
        <button type="submit" id="subm" name="submit" class="eut px-3 py-1 text-sm font-bold text-gray-100 transition-colors duration-300 transform bg-gray-600 rounded cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-500">Enroll</button>                
    </div>
</form>
<?php }} else {
    echo 'No records found...';
}
?>
```

Whenever I clicked a button it posts same data in every button.

```
<script>
var submit1 = document.querySelectorAll(".eut");
for (let i = 0; i < submit1.length; i++) {
    submit1[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        var s1 = document.getElementById("unq").value;    
        formData.append("us1", s1);
        var url = "enroll.php";
        axios.post(url, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data
            }
        })
    });
}
```

I want to post form in different form but when I tried to click the buttons it posts same data of the first form.

Comment: IDs must be unique, you are violating that simple & basic rule with the content you are creating inside your loop there. `document.getElementById("unq")` will only ever access the _first_ element with that ID in your broken document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) `id` is treated as a unique parameter in jQuery when it is used, which means only a single element throughout the document can have that id, so in your case `document.getElementById("unq")` will only give you first form element

B) Repetition of button click code is not required at all, on clicking any button gets its closest form and submit it. To do so, do it like below:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".eut").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData( $(this).closest('form')[0] );
            var url = "enroll.php";
            axios.post(url, formData, {             
                headers: {              
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }       
            })  
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```